# couchdb views os_process_error - big documents

Tags: view, couchdb, documents

I have a database that we're filling up with documents, some of which are 10 KB, and some of which that are ~70 MB in size.

Any view that tries to load these large documents fails with error: **{"error":"os_process_error","reason":"{exit_status,0}"}**, even this elementary one:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(null, "test");
}
```

**os_process_error** is set to 35000, but calling the view dies in ~15 seconds:

```
time curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/portal_production/_design/all_data_keys/_view/view1
{"error":"os_process_error","reason":"{exit_status,0}"}

real    0m15.907s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.000s
```

From a few other threads, seems like this is related stack size: [couchdb issue thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-893). I've applied this patch to increase the stack size, although I couldn't find a reference to the method's value. So I'm shooting in the dark a bit.

Soooo.... the real question is: what is the correct approach for using views on large documents? I'm sure I'm not the first to have this problem.

Comment: Consider not to use DB... There are many "file system vs. DB for blob storage" threads... Make sure to search for some and check out options...

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think about this. CouchDB is nice because Elasticsearch index'es into it, and I'd like to have searchable documents still. But maybe there's something in the middle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd hit `couchjs` stack size limit. If you're using CouchDB 1.4.0+ his size is limited by 64 MiB by default. You may increase it by specifying `-S <number-of-bytes>` option for JavaScript query server in CouchDB config. For instance, to set stack size to 128 MiB your config value will looks like:

```
[query_servers]
javascript = /usr/bin/couchjs -S 134217728 /usr/share/couchdb/server/main.js
```

Note, that `/usr/bin/couchjs` may be different for you depending on your OS. After adding this changes you need to restart CouchDB.

If you'll try to update JavaScript query server config though HTTP API, make sure to `kill` all `couchjs` processes from shell to let them apply changes.

If your CouchDB version is <1.4 try to upgrade first.

Comment: This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for! I'm upgrading to 1.4 right now, so I'll share my results when that's done.

Comment: Finally finished the upgrade to 1.5.0, which created some more issues. But this one is fixed.

Comment: It worked for me with CouchDB 1.6.1, but not with CouchDB 2.0.0. See https://github.com/apache/couchdb-couch/pull/216

Comment: so what's probably solution for couchDB 2.x?