# How can I optimize the view and avoid timeout error

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, timeout, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I had a view map/reduce defined as following,as most of documents have no doc.emails[i].userTypecode elements in couchdb,  so it is running the view takes too long causing couch to give up / time out: the error is Error: os_preocess_error, OS process time out, can some one help me how to figure out this issue and how to optimize the map/reduce? thank you

I checked there are similar issue happened , but no idea how that were fixed?https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1333
[couchdb views os_process_error - big documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273736/couchdb-views-os-process-error-big-documents)

map:

```
  function(doc) {
                for (var i in doc.emails) {
                     if (doc.emails[i].userTypecode == "false" || !doc.users[i].userTypecode) {
                      emit(doc.emails[i].emailAddress.toLowerCase().split('@')[1],doc);   
                 }
             }
            }
```

reduce:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
      return values;
}
```

Comment: Your reduce function is wrong - it won't work on rereduce.  I don't think you want a reduce function at all.

Also, your emit doesn't make much sense.  You are emitting as a key the right side of the @ (e.g. 'gmail.com'), which seems odd, and also you're emitting the doc, which is not a good idea because it makes the index unnecessarily large.

Comment: @john_omalley, thank you for your response, what do you mean the odd of  emit key, I want to get all the email address domain as the key in the view, and even if I emit some of other fields replace with Doc, it is still running slow

Comment: `"foobar@gmail.com".split('@')[1]` evaluates to `gmail.com`.

Also `emit(someKey, doc)` isnt a good idea because it puts the doc in the index that is built (as of couchdb 1.6.1 at least).  You can always use include_docs=true in the view query to get the docs.