# how to have couchdb query server started?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I raised issues that related to [One couchdb view suddenly started timing out:OS process time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101129/one-couchdb-view-suddenly-started-timing-outos-process-time-out) and [How can I optimize the view and avoid timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119889/how-can-i-optimize-the-view-and-avoid-timeout-error)

As I checked out,the reason that the OS time out issue  that couchdb query server could not even start. but I do not know how to start couchdb query server, please advise, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query servers are defined in the couchdb config and are started on couchdb boot. See here - http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/query-servers.html.

So you shouldn't have to start the query server yourself. Look at the couchdb logs, is there any stack trace indicating why it didn't start correctly?