# CouchDB unable to create simple view with time-out error

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am new to CouchDB and trying to create a view to a database.

Even with a default simple view, as shown below

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc._id, 1);
}
```

I got a timed out error for a database with only 800 documents (total size of the database is `sizes.external`=800MB with `sizes.actual`=200MB file-size). Adding this view to a smaller database of only 4MB returned a view quickly.

here are the logs when the error was triggered

```
[error] 2023-11-24T04:52:16.601473Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.4020.724> d4811f5123 rexi_server: from: couchdb@127.0.0.1(<0.3758.724>) mfa: fabric_rpc:map_view/5 throw:{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}} [{couch_mrview_util,get_view_index_state,5,[{file,"src/couch_mrview_util.erl"},{line$
[info] 2023-11-24T04:52:24.104869Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3682.724> -------- Starting index update for db: shards/80000000-ffffffff/dbname.1700199178 idx: _design/dbquery
[info] 2023-11-24T04:53:12.501436Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.406.0> -------- couch_proc_manager <0.5169.724> died normal
[error] 2023-11-24T04:53:12.501756Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.4866.724> -------- OS Process Error <0.5169.724> :: {os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}
[error] 2023-11-24T04:53:12.502285Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 emulator -------- Error in process <0.4866.724> on node 'couchdb@127.0.0.1' with exit value:
{{nocatch,{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}},[{couch_os_process,prompt,2,[{file,"src/couch_os_process.erl"},{line,59}]},{couch_query_servers,map_doc_raw,2,[{file,"src/couch_query_servers.erl"},{line,73}]},{couch_mrview_updater,'-map_docs/2-fun-0-',3,[{file,"src/couch_mrview_updat$
```

I am just a little bit surprised by the scalability of CouchDB for handling a 200MB database and thought it should handle it easily. My database server is a capable, dedicated Linux server with plenty of memory and disk space.

is this result expected?

Comment: Guessing you have some docs in there that are quite large? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273736/152786

Comment: indeed. I read about that post shortly after I posted this question and adding -S in the couchjs command fixed the issue. My docs are ranging between a few hundred KB to 8MB (size limit) and it appears that having docs of a few MBs will likely trigger the stack limit issue.